# Showing that asymptotic normality implies consistency.

Tags: statistics, probability-theory

In a statistics book i'm reading, it is postulated that asymptotic normality of an estimator implies consistency. That is
$$
\hat{\theta}_n \stackrel{as}{\sim} \mathcal{N}(\theta_0, \frac{1}{n}\sigma(\theta_0)) \Rightarrow P_{\theta_0}(|\hat{\theta}_n - \theta_0|>\epsilon ) \to 0
$$
when $n\to\infty$, for all $\theta_0 \in \Theta$ and $\epsilon>0$.

I am trying to prove this, but i can't seem to get a breakthrough.

If anyone could shed some light on how this is proven, i would be very grateful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If the distribution of $X_n$ is $\mathcal N(x,\sigma_n^2)$ and $\sigma_n^2\to0$, then $X_n\to x$ in probability, that is, $P[|X_n-x|\geqslant\epsilon]\to0$ for every positive $\epsilon$.

To prove this, an easy route is to use Bienaymé-Chebyhev inequality, to the effect that $E[X_n]=x$ and $\mathrm{var}(X_n)=\sigma_n^2$ hence
$$
P[|X_n-x|\geqslant\epsilon]=P[|X_n-E[X_n]|\geqslant\epsilon]\leqslant\frac{\mathrm{var}(X_n)}{\epsilon^2}=\frac{\sigma_n^2}{\epsilon^2}.
$$

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. The only thing that i cant comprehend is that in order to use Chebyshev's inequality i need to know that the variance of $X_n$ is in fact $\sigma^2_n$, and i'm not really sure what argument i need to make in order to use it on something that has an asymptotic variance.

Comment: Isn't this an *assumption* in your question?

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong, but as i have understood it
when
$$
X_n \stackrel{as}{\sim} N (x , \sigma^2_n)
$$
Then $Var(X_n)\neq \sigma^2_n$ (equality only holds in the limit.)
And as i see it i need to use Chebyshev's inequality before taking the limit in n.

Correct me if im wrong, but really sure about this.

Comment: not really sure about this*

Comment: Which limit? Since $\sigma_n^2\to0$, in the limit $n\to\infty$, $X_n\sim$... what exactly? It seems you need to seriously explain what you mean by this hypothesis if not what I considered in my post.

Answer (score 3):

A more concise answer follows using the $O_p$ and $o_p$ notation for stochastic orders. Your premise is that

$$\sqrt{n}(\theta_n-\theta_0)\overset{d}{\rightarrow}Z$$

where $Z$ is normally distributed with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma(\theta_0)$. Therefore

$$\theta_n-\theta_0=O_p\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\Rightarrow \theta_n-\theta_0= o_p(1)$$

hence $\theta_n-\theta_0\overset{p}{\rightarrow}0$, which finishes the proof.

Comment: Can you give more intuition about the last part? I mean, why does $\hat{\theta}_{n} - \theta_{0}$ being $o_{p}(1)$ implies convergence in probability to zero?

Comment: It is the definition of $o_p(1)$, so it is an "if and only if" statement.  Am I understanding your question correctly, @S.Cow ?

Comment: What about the first part? Why does asymptotic normality imply that the error is bounded in probability? Is it simply because of the shape of the normal distribution, i.e. that its tail probabilities are zero for large enough values?

Comment: It is simpler than that: $X_n=O_p(R_n)$ means $X_n=Y_nR_n$ and $Y_n=O_p(1)$.