# Source needed: Does asymptotic normality yield asymptotic unbiasedness and consistency?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, asymptotics, normal-distribution

Assume that $$\sqrt{n}(\hat g - g(\theta)) \xrightarrow{d} Z, $$ where $Z$ is $N(0,\sigma^2)$.

Does this already imply asymptotic unbiasedness and/or consistency, i.e.,

$$ E[\hat g] \rightarrow g(\theta) ~~~\mbox{and/or}~~~ \hat g \xrightarrow{P} g(\theta)?$$

I am aware of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/409429/showing-that-asymptotic-normality-implies-consistency) post, but it does not answer my question as I do not know the distributions of $\hat g$ for finite $n$.

Can anyone point to some literature that answers these questions positively or negatively?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: http://www.stat.tamu.edu/~hart/611/proof.p118.pdf is helpful/relevant for showing that this implies consistency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [paper](http://faculty.agecon.vt.edu/moeltner/AAEC5126/module3/Asymptotics.pdf) will help you out.

The definition of Asymptotic Expecatation is given [here](http://pages.stat.wisc.edu/~doksum/STAT709/n709-27.pdf). I'll paraphrase the relevant parts. This link is an excerpt of the book "Mathematical Statistics" 2nd ed., by Jun Shao. I highly recommend this book if you want to get into this kind of statistical work.

*Asymptotic Expectation*: Let $\xi,\xi_1,\xi_2...$ be random varibles and $\{a_n\}$ a sequence of *positive* numbers satisfying $a_n\rightarrow \infty$. If $a_n\xi_n \xrightarrow{d} \xi$ and $E[|\xi|]<\infty$ then $\frac{E[\xi]}{a_n}$ is the *asymptotic expectation* of $\xi_n$.

The *asymptotic bias* of an estimator $T_n$ for parameter $\theta$ is defined as the asymptotic expectation of $T_n-\theta$. If the asymptotic bias is zero, then it is called asymptotically unbiased.

We can related the above concepts to your specific case:

- $\xi = Z$
- $\xi_n = \hat g_n-g(\theta)$
- $a_n=\sqrt{n}$

Note that $a_n\rightarrow \infty$ and we are assuming that $\sqrt{n}(\hat g_n-g(\theta)) \xrightarrow{d} Z$ which matches with the second condition on convergence in distribution. Now, since $Z\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$, we know that $E[|Z|]<\infty$, satifying the final condition. Therefore, the asymptotic bias of $\hat g_n-g(\theta)$ is $\frac{E[Z]}{\sqrt{n}} = 0$. Hence, $\hat g_n$ is an asymptotically unbiased estimator of $g(\theta)$.

To show consistency, we need to show that it is not only asymptotically unbiased, but that its asymptotic mse goes to $0$. That is, we need to find the asymptotic expectation of $\xi_n^2$, which is defined to be $\frac{E[\xi^2]}{a_n}$ based on similar conditions to the asymptotic expectation. Again, we know that since Z is the standard normal, then $E[Z^2]=1<\infty$, since $Z^2$ will have a $\chi^2_1$ distribution.

Therefore, the $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{E[Z^2]}{\sqrt{n}} = 0$, hence the estimator is asymptotically consistent.