# Asymptotic normality implies consistency?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, asymptotics

> Does asymptotic normality imply consistency?

Update: Asymptotic normality implies consistency, as proven in this quesiton: [Showing that asymptotic normality implies consistency.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/409429/showing-that-asymptotic-normality-implies-consistency)

Comment: Among possible examples, take the $U(0,\theta)$ distribution. If $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ is a random sample drawn from the above distribution, then it is not difficult to show that $\hat\theta_{\text{MLE}}=\max_{1\le i\le n}X_i$ is a consistent estimator of $\theta$, but its asymptotic distribution is not normal.

Comment: Why did you change the entire question after accepting an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take any example of a consistent and asymptotically normal estimator $\hat\theta_n$ and spoil it like this: $\tilde\theta_n=\hat\theta_n+\frac{1}{n^{1/3}}$.

Comment: It is indeed easy to show that it is still consistent, but how exactly do you show that it's not asymptotically normal anymore?

Comment: $\sqrt{n}\cdot \frac{1}{n^{1/3}}\to \infty$ as $n\to\infty$. Check definition of asymptotic normality.